# Can Google BigQuery's internal data storage location be pointed to another location like local in-house infrastructure?

Tags: google-bigquery

I would really like to use BigQuery for data analytics and developing business intelligence. The only concern is that some of our clients are not comfortable with cloud storage, so we have in-house servers storing their data for all our other processes. So far as I can tell, BigQuery offers no flexibility on storage of datasets aside from specifying which location in the cloud (US or EU) should be used. Is there any way to specify that BigQuery datasets are to be stored in local clusters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to point BigQuery storage to servers outside of Cloud. BigQuery supports federated query from outside of its internal storage, but it still needs to be in Google Cloud Storage or on Google Drive (and in the future perhaps on other Cloud storage systems).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative answer to the technically correct one provided above; while you cannot specify a storage location outside of Google's infrastructure for BigQuery to access, it is worth noting that BigQuery is simply a fully managed (and highly optimized) version of the open source tool, [Drill](https://drill.apache.org/). Drill is essentially the query execution engine of BigQuery entirely uncoupled from the storage layer that Google uses (Colossus).

We leverage both BigQuery and Drill heavily at my company, and are very happy with both, albeit for different uses.